# Changing debug mode into magento 2.3 losses theme css content

Tags: magento2, css, developer-mode, deploy

My site was in production mode. i changed it to developer mode. i ran all the commands. Static content deploy command too.
But site is looking weird now.
Can you guys please suggest something.
https://e92rduand89atx1x.mojostratus.io/  link for reference.

Comment: Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: i think try this command `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -a frontend en_US Infortis/ultimo` but first you remove `var/cache` and `var/view_preprocessed` and remove the `pub/static`

Comment: This command seems to be invalid. What does -a represent?? where do i put -f??

Comment: try to -f in deploy command

Comment: What should be the command with -f??

Comment: php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy en_US -a frontend en_US Infortis/ultimo -f this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108939/discussion-between-nafisa-and-mohit-patel).